# Convert list of boolean strings to a nested list of variable-sized elements in Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, boolean

I have a PySpark DataFrame with a column that contains a list of boolean string values indicating the location of the element in `orientation` defined below:

```
orientation = np.array(['L', 'D', 'U', 'R'])

df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(sequence=['1000', '0011']),
                 Row(sequence=['0100', '1001', '0010']),
                 Row(sequence=['1011', '0100']),
                 Row(sequence=['1111'])]).toDF()
```

It can be assumed that both boolean strings and `orientations` will always be length 4, and `0000` is never in `df`.

Using PySpark, how can I transform this column (order preserving ideally) into the following expected result?

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(sequence=[['L'], ['U', 'R']]),
                 Row(sequence=[['D'], ['L', 'R'], ['U']]),
                 Row(sequence=[['L', 'U', 'R'], ['D']]),
                 Row(sequence=[['L', 'D', 'U', 'R']])]).toDF()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with `transform` higher order function.

Here's an example - i've created multiple columns for better understanding, but you can merge them

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('orient', 
               func.array(*[func.lit(k) for k in orientation])
               ). \
    withColumn('blah', 
               func.transform('sequence', lambda x: func.split(x, ''))
               ). \
    withColumn('blah2', 
               func.transform('blah', 
                              lambda x: func.zip_with(x, 'orient', 
                                                      lambda y, z: func.struct(y.alias('seq'), z.alias('ori'))
                                                      )
                              )
               ). \
    withColumn('blah3', 
               func.transform('blah2', lambda x: func.filter(x, lambda y: y.seq == 1))
               ). \
    withColumn('new_sequence', 
               func.transform('blah3', lambda x: func.transform(x, lambda y: y.ori))
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------+------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
# |sequence          |orient      |blah                                      |blah2                                                                                                 |blah3                                 |new_sequence      |
# +------------------+------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
# |[1000, 0011]      |[L, D, U, R]|[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]]              |[[{1, L}, {0, D}, {0, U}, {0, R}], [{0, L}, {0, D}, {1, U}, {1, R}]]                                  |[[{1, L}], [{1, U}, {1, R}]]          |[[L], [U, R]]     |
# |[0100, 1001, 0010]|[L, D, U, R]|[[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]]|[[{0, L}, {1, D}, {0, U}, {0, R}], [{1, L}, {0, D}, {0, U}, {1, R}], [{0, L}, {0, D}, {1, U}, {0, R}]]|[[{1, D}], [{1, L}, {1, R}], [{1, U}]]|[[D], [L, R], [U]]|
# |[1011, 0100]      |[L, D, U, R]|[[1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]              |[[{1, L}, {0, D}, {1, U}, {1, R}], [{0, L}, {1, D}, {0, U}, {0, R}]]                                  |[[{1, L}, {1, U}, {1, R}], [{1, D}]]  |[[L, U, R], [D]]  |
# |[1111]            |[L, D, U, R]|[[1, 1, 1, 1]]                            |[[{1, L}, {1, D}, {1, U}, {1, R}]]                                                                    |[[{1, L}, {1, D}, {1, U}, {1, R}]]    |[[L, D, U, R]]    |
# +------------------+------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+
```

---

`blah` is where we split the boolean strings to create an array. `blah2` uses those arrays and zips the elements with that of `orientation` - preserving order - to create array of structs. `blah3` filters the structs where the boolean string is `"1"`. finally, `new_sequence` retains the orientation part only, to give the new sequence that is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a UDF here since it will help you to keep the code clean:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql import Row

def transform(r):
  mapper = {
        0 : 'L',
        1 : 'D',
        2 : 'U',
        3 : 'R'
  }
  row = []
  for ar in r: # each item in the array will be a binary sequence
    mapped = []
    for idx, bitem in enumerate(list(ar)): # for each binary sequence get the corresponding letter based on the mapper
      if bitem == '1':
        mapped.append(mapper[idx])
    row.append(mapped)
  return row

udf_from_binary = udf(transform)

df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(sequence=['1000', '0011']),
                 Row(sequence=['0100', '1001', '0010']),
                 Row(sequence=['1011', '0100']),
                 Row(sequence=['1111'])]).toDF()
  

df.withColumn("sequence", udf_from_binary(col("sequence"))).show(10, False)

+------------------+
|sequence          |
+------------------+
|[[L], [U, R]]     |
|[[D], [L, R], [U]]|
|[[L, U, R], [D]]  |
|[[L, D, U, R]]    |
+------------------+
```

The logic is based on the `mapper` dictionary. When binary == `1` the index of the binary is mapped into the corresponding letter. For each sequence we create a new array, namely `mapped`. Eventually all the `mapped` arrays are merged together and compose the final array called `row`, which will be the transformed row we are seeking for.